# How to Widen My Website Without Recoding Everything

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm not going to lie. I'm not a professional coder, I've learned everything I know from forums and I don't do things according to the book. I kind of cheat the system. Anyway, I've been editing a website on Enjin, it's a gaming platform where you can insert html/css modules that alter the layout and design. I've coded the entire thing, using divs and what-not for my friend's server. Once again I want to reiterate that I'm not a professional, I do it for fun and for free. Now, I'm in a predicament. I want to widen everything I've done, without going in and recoding all my divs since I used px to define them all. Here is my code, and I'll insert a link to the site. Any help will be appreciated..

[Here's the site] http://www.terracrafters.net/test

```
  .m_minecraftserverstatus_new.preset_43030555 {
    background-color: #1e2124;
    opacity: .9;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 0px solid #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }

    BODY {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    }

    .breaker {
    opacity: 0;
    } 

    .m_minecraftserverstatus_new.preset_43030555 .top-area {
    background-color: #1e2124;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    }

    .body-wrap-3 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    background-image: url(https://assets-cloud.enjin.com/themes/1487945582_Background.png);
    }

    .body-wrap-3, #page {
    min-width: 0 !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    }

    #page-wrap {
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 60px auto 30px;
    }

    .logo {
    z-index: 10000000;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left:38%;
    margin-bottom: -65px;
    }

    .container {
    margin-top: -16px;
    }

    body #site-body {
    min-height: 750px;
    max-width: 1100px !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/17521938_1421397851215990_1860950770_o.png?oh=a7575fe8a4e2aca7bc01d19f859148e0&oe=58D973CA);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 2000px;
    background-position-y: -260px;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    } 


    a, p, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, span {
    font-family: MedievalSharp;  sans-serif;
    }

    .abmpro {
    background: transparent;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 800px;
    margin-top: 105px;
    z-index: 10000000;
    position: absolute;
    }


    .navbar {
    background-color: #1f4636;
    height: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4%;
    width: 67.35%;
    margin-left: -.7%;
    margin-top: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .navbar img{
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(-255.5%) translateY(40%);
    }

    .navbar a{
    -webkit-text-emphasis-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 25px;
    height: 35px;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
    color: antiquewhite;
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
        width: 0;
        transition: 0.4s ease-in;
        -o-transition: 0.4s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: 0.4s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: 0.4s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in;
        overflow: hidden;
    padding: 25px;
    height: 35px;
    }

    .navbar p {
    margin-bottom: -5px; 
    }

    .abmhomeconent {
    background-color: #452121;
    margin-left: -11px;
    margin-right: -11px;
    margin-top: -5.1%;
    margin-bottom: -39px;
    }

    .simple-ss {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5em;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: -11px;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/vqs1TBE.jpg");
    background-position: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 470px;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
     animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    }
    @keyframes slide {
  0% {background-position: 0 -100;}
 50% {background-position: 0 -50px;}
  100% {background-position: 0 0px;}
    }

    #enjin-bar .left {
    display:inherit;
    z-index:50000;
    }

    .m_html p {
    min-height: 1.25em;
    margin-bottom: -64px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    margin-left: 405px;
    }

    #enjin-bar {
    right: .0%;
    top: 7.55%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #8a8a8a;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:50000;
    }

    #page-footer {
    display:none;
    }

    #page-footer left {
    display: none;
    }

    #page-footer right {
    display: none;
    }

    .container_body {
    margin-top:-.2%;
    margin-left:-.1%;
        margin-right:-.1%;
    }

    .m_news.main {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .m_news {
    background-color: #1e2124;
    margin-left: .1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    opacity: .9;
    }
     .m_news.main .float-manage,.m_news.main .float-rss {
        margin-top:0px;
    }
    .m_news .heading {
        background:#D8D8D8;
        height:25px;
        padding:20px;
    }
    .m_news.main .article.first .heading {
        margin-right:0!important;
    }
    .m_news.main .heading .title, .m_news.viewarticle .heading .title {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    }
    .m_news .heading .title a {
        color:#000;
        font-weight:300!important;
    }
    .m_news .heading .info {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    .m_news .heading .info .date {
        visibility:visible;
        float:right;
        position:relative;
        top:-30px;
        font-size:22px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        color:#fff;

    }
    .m_news .article .article-content {
        font-size:14px;
        line-height:20px;
        text-align:justify;
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }
    .m_news.viewarticle .m_plugin_comment {
        width:94%;
        margin:50px auto 0 auto;
    }
    .m_news.viewarticle .m_plugin_comment .block-title {
        background:transparent;
        border-bottom:2px solid #FFA62F;
        color:#FFA62F;
    }
    .m_news .article .heading .element_avatar {
    margin-top: -2.4%;
    margin-left:-6px;
    }

    .post_interact_like_list {
    width:100px;
    }

    .post_interact_like_list_hidden{
    width:100px;
    }













    #boot_admin{
    margin-top:0px;

    }

    #boot_admin a:nth-child(1){
    display:none;
    }

    #boot_profile{
    height:30px;

    }

    #boot_profile .element_username{
    color: black !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;

    }

    #boot_profile span:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51) !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    }




    /*Changes our enjin dropdown caret to something that is close to twitter's     caret object(Part 2 for border)*/
    #enjin-bar .arrow:after{
    border-top:6px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:rgba(255, 255, 255);
    border-right:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:6px solid transparent;
    border-left:6px solid transparent;
top:3px;
}

/*Changes the style of our entire dropdown box to mimick Boot strap style*/
.element_dropdown_menu.element_popup.enjinbar-menu{
margin-top:26px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
z-index:99999;
color:black;
}

/*Our inner elements of our entire enjin drop down*/
.element_popup .inner {
background-color: white !important;
margin-left:10px;
text-decroation:none;
padding:0px 0;
margin:-1px -25px 0;
list-style:none;
border:solid gray 1px;
-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
-moz-background-clip:padding;
background-clip:padding-box;
color:black;

}

/*Text - Our inner elements of our entire enjin drop down*/
.element_popup .inner li a{
color:#333;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Arial;
padding:6px 20px !important;
}

/*Text - Hover - Our inner elements of our entire enjin drop down*/
.element_popup .inner .menu-link:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#0081c2;
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}

/*Enjin Divider lines to look...better*/
.element_popup .inner .menu-divider-line{
background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid white !important;
height:1px !important;
opacity:0.4;
}

/*Profile drop down item hover events*/
.element_popup .inner .item:hover{
background-color: rgb(0, 129, 194);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0, 136, 204), rgb(0, 119, 179));
}

/*Profile drop down text style*/
.element_popup .inner .item a{
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: normal;
margin-bottom:-5px; /*Reduces some spacing..since menu is huge*/
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
font-family:arial;
}

/*Profile drop down text style - hover*/
.element_popup .inner .item a:hover{
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

/*Font,text - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.sitebox a {
font-size:10px !important;
color:#333;
margin-left:-20px;
background-color:transparent;
}

/*Font,text, make less default space - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.enjinbar-menu-user .sitebox{
margin-bottom:10px;
}

/*That damn gear! - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.enjinbar-menu-user .sitebox .gear {
background-position: 40px 0px; /*Removes Enjin's mysterious extra icons*/ }

/*Text for site urls - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.sitebox .url{
color:#333;
}

/*Our visible username text*/
#enjin-bar .element_username{
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}

/*Removes our likes etc.*/
#enjin-bar #enjin-bar-likes{
display:none !important;
}

/*Removes site info,site name and our admin gear*/
#enjin-bar .left a:nth-of-type(1),#enjin-bar .left a:nth-of-type(2),#enjin-bar .left a:nth-of-type(3){
display:none !important;
}

/*creates a default right position for our admin, fixed, position manually on your fixed nav*/
#enjin-bar .left{
margin-top:8px;
z-index:9999;
margin-left:530px;
position:fixed;
}



/*Our admin text on hover*/
#enjin-bar .left a:hover{
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
text-decoration:none;
}

 .sitebox {
     display:none;
}
/*END Enjin bar nav positioning*/

/*profile*/

.v2_system_social .widget_owner {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.v2_system_social .middle_inner, .v2_system_social .sidebar_widget_inner, .v2_system_social .profile_menu .menu_popup_inner {
    border: 0px;
    border-color: transparent;
    padding: 1px;
}

.v2_system_social table.header .cover {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 173px;
    max-width: 898px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -1px -1px;
    position: relative;
}

.v2_system_social table.header .avatar {
    width: 173px;
    height: 173px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -1px -1px;
}

.v2_system_social .middle {
    margin: 0 400px 0 78px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    min-height: 600px;
}

.v2_system_social .sidebar_widget {
    width: 383px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.sidebar_widget {
    background-color: #613D41;
}
body.liquid .v2_system_social {
    max-width: 1090px;
    min-width: 954px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1067px;
}

#avatar img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    /* float: right; */
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -2.8%;
    /* margin-left: 700px; */
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.m_pointsdisplay {
display:none;
}
.v2_system_social .wall .share_closed, .v2_system_social .wall .share, .v2_system_social .wall .share_add_container {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #1a1a1a;
    width: 67%;
}
.v2_system_social .widget_owner .logo {
    float: left;
    width: 74px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
















.container_body .container_right {
    /* background-image: url(https://assets-cloud.enjin.com/themes/1350633694_re.png); */
    /* width: 13px; */
    /* background-color: transparent; */
}

.m_shoutbox {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1e2124;
    opacity: .9;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)
(index):477

#enjin-bar .left {
    display:none;
}




#boot_admin{
margin-top:0px;

}

#boot_admin a:nth-child(1){
display:none;
}

#boot_profile{
height:30px;

}

#boot_profile .element_username{
color: black !important;
text-decoration:none !important;

}

#boot_profile span:hover{
background-color: transparent;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51) !important;
text-decoration: none;
}




/*Changes our enjin dropdown caret to something that is close to twitter's caret object(Part 2 for border)*/
#enjin-bar .arrow:after{
border-top:6px solid transparent;
border-top-color:rgba(255, 255, 255);
border-right:6px solid transparent;
border-bottom:6px solid transparent;
border-left:6px solid transparent;
top:3px;
}

/*Changes the style of our entire dropdown box to mimick Boot strap style*/
.element_dropdown_menu.element_popup.enjinbar-menu{
margin-top:26px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
z-index:99999;
color:black;
}

/*Our inner elements of our entire enjin drop down*/
.element_popup .inner {
background-color: white !important;
margin-left:10px;
text-decroation:none;
padding:0px 0;
margin:-1px -25px 0;
list-style:none;
border:solid gray 1px;
-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
-moz-background-clip:padding;
background-clip:padding-box;
color:black;

}

/*Text - Our inner elements of our entire enjin drop down*/
.element_popup .inner li a{
color:#333;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Arial;
padding:6px 20px !important;
}

/*Text - Hover - Our inner elements of our entire enjin drop down*/
.element_popup .inner .menu-link:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#0081c2;
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}

/*Enjin Divider lines to look...better*/
.element_popup .inner .menu-divider-line{
background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid white !important;
height:1px !important;
opacity:0.4;
}

/*Profile drop down item hover events*/
.element_popup .inner .item:hover{
background-color: rgb(0, 129, 194);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0, 136, 204), rgb(0, 119, 179));
}

/*Profile drop down text style*/
.element_popup .inner .item a{
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: normal;
margin-bottom:-5px; /*Reduces some spacing..since menu is huge*/
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
font-family:arial;
}

/*Profile drop down text style - hover*/
.element_popup .inner .item a:hover{
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

/*Font,text - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.sitebox a {
font-size:10px !important;
color:#333;
margin-left:-20px;
background-color:transparent;
}

/*Font,text, make less default space - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.enjinbar-menu-user .sitebox{
margin-bottom:10px;
}

/*That damn gear! - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.enjinbar-menu-user .sitebox .gear {
background-position: 40px 0px; /*Removes Enjin's mysterious extra icons*/ }

/*Text for site urls - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.sitebox .url{
color:#333;
}

/*Our visible username text*/
#enjin-bar .element_username{
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}

/*Removes our likes etc.*/
#enjin-bar #enjin-bar-likes{
display:none !important;
}

/*Removes site info,site name and our admin gear*/
#enjin-bar .left a:nth-of-type(1),#enjin-bar .left a:nth-of-type(2),#enjin-bar .left a:nth-of-type(3){
display:none !important;
}

/*creates a default right position for our admin, fixed, position manually on your fixed nav*/
#enjin-bar .left{
margin-top:8px;
z-index:9999;
margin-left:530px;
position:fixed;
}



/*Our admin text on hover*/
#enjin-bar .left a:hover{
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
text-decoration:none;
}

/*END Enjin bar nav positioning*/
```

Comment: Yes, and no,  you don't have to go redo *everything*. You do however, have to go redo all the widths in css.

Comment: While I appreciate you're not very experienced with coding, you'll need to help us solve the problem by describing it more clearly. What exactly does "*widen everything*" entail? You want the container to occupy more of the screen width? On what size of device? On my laptop the page occupies nearly the entire screen, and on my monitor, it occupies about 70%. Would you like it to be 100% on **any** device?

Comment: "Once again I want to illiterate that I'm not a professional" -- I _think_ you meant _"reiterate"_ ... :)

Comment: My bad, I did mean reiterate (Funny that of all words I would misspell it as would be illiterate. That's gold)! Haha, but basically, the person who I'm doing the website for asked that I have the main part of the website, meaning everything except for the background be wider so that it would take up more of the computer screen.. if that makes since? I guess the width is appearing smaller on different screens. If I open the website in internet explored everything is significantly smaller compared to chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's safe to say no one is going to read allllll that css ;) but having a quick look at your site, there are two obvious things to change. This is all of course dependent on what you mean by widen everything. But you have both `body #site-body` and `#page-wrap` set to `max-width:100px`.
You could remove this, or alter it, and it will stretch your main content across the page. I suspect there is something for higher up the page too with the image and menu.

I would also look to reduce the amount of `!important`s you have in there as they can get you into all sorts of hassles with trying to work out your styling. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! This is the answer I was looking for.